# Is it possible to delete the last line within a file using a command?

Tags: centos, cron

I've accidently distributed a line to /etc/crontab on many servers and i noticed that there's a typo in this line and i need to change it on all servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to fix the typo rather than just delete the last line

```
sed -i '$ s/typotext/correcttext/ /var/spool/cron/user
```

You should be able to edit the crontab files directly for newer versions of cron as it checks for changes very minute.

Answer (score 1):

If your sed supports in-place editing, then,

```
sed -i '$d' file
```

if not, you'll need to use a compound command such as,

```
cat file | sed '$d' > newfile; mv newfile file
```

Answer (score 0):

use `head`

```
user@host$ cat <<EOF > test.txt
1
2
3
4
EOF
user@host$ head -n -1 test.txt | sponge test.txt
user@host$ cat test.txt
1
2
3
user@host$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'd|x' /etc/crobtab
```

1. `d` delete line
2. `x` save and quit

Answer (score -1):

See this forum article on unix.com for the answer:

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/25027-delete-last-line.html

sed -e '$d' input.file > output.file

or

head -$((`wc -l file | awk '{print $1}'` - 1)) file

Comment: Please don't post just a link as an answer but give at least a summary of the info found in this link.